Setting focus on heading in modal after user clicks edit button
I have started working on LWC.
The page has an "Edit" button. When the user clicks edit button a modal opens which contains a form with heading and fields.
When the form has rendered, I want the focus to go on the heading and not the form field. This is needed as part of accessibility guidelines.
I have added the tabIndex attribute in the heading to "-1".
In the javascript file, I tried setting the heading.focus() in render and renderCallback which are the lifecycle hooks but that does not seem to work as looks like after render the components don't become interactive(being able to take foucus) immediately.
Which lifecycle hook would be the suitable choice for this scenario.

Welcome to SFSE! Please take a moment to read How to Ask and take the tour. Including a Minimal, Complete and Reproducible example would be helpful.

I assume you use the proper lightning modal.
The correct lifecycle hook is the renderedCallback(), because in the connectedCallback() there is not yet an element that could be focused. I faced no difficulties setting this up. Below the code of the modal.
HTML
<template>
    <lightning-modal-header label="Header">
        <h1 lwc:ref="focusPoint" class="shadow slds-box" tabindex="-1">Please focus me!</h1>
    </lightning-modal-header>
    <lightning-modal-body>
        <input type="text" class="shadow" tabindex="0"></input>
    </lightning-modal-body>
</template>

Javascript
import LightningModal from 'lightning/modal';

export default class MyModal extends LightningModal {
    renderedCallback() { 
        this.refs.focusPoint.focus(); 
    }
}

CSS
.shadow:focus {
    border: 10px solid green;
}

I've added CSS to proof the point. Have a go :-)
